# How can i fill a tree and retrieve the values in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am developing an application for training chess. The idea is to upload a file PGN Portable Game Notation ( no PNG is image format) , which is a file where the data of an item and also the moves are stored.

Each move can have zero , one or more variations . I declare ​​a class to fill the tree and then to follow it.

Then the class that I created :

```
public class Movida 
{
    private int numeroMovida;
    private string algebraicMove;
    private int token;
    private string comentario;
    private List<Movida> variaciones = new List<Movida>(); 

    public Movida(int numeroMovida, string algebraicMove, int token, string comentario, List<Movida> variaciones) {
        this.numeroMovida = numeroMovida;
        this.algebraicMove = algebraicMove;
        this.token = token;
        this.comentario = comentario;
        this.variaciones = null;
    }
    public void agregarMovida(Movida movida) {
        variaciones.Add(movida);
    }
    public List<Movida> obtenerVariaciones() {
        return variaciones;
    }
}
```

I think I need to make a function to enter fill the tree recursively , just to get moved back. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be more clear.

Comment: These are chess moves in PGN format. 
1. Nf3+ $18 gxf3 (1…Bxf3 2. a6 {This is a comment} a3 (2… b3) 3.Nxe1 Raxe1 $19 {This is other comment} (3…Rfxe1) (3… Nxe1) (3. Kh2)) (1…Kh1) 2. Rf5 (2. Qh4 f4 3. Qxf4)

Comment: The $ symbol are tokens that says how strength the move was, and there are comments between { }. Each move can have token and comment or not.

Comment: I am doing a chess trainer that load the PGN file, the position on a board and ask the player for the correct move. I load the board but I am in a big trouble dealing with the moves. I need to parse them to a class and later to retrieve the moves but beginning from the most internal variation (from more nested to the main line).